# Mechanics of a falling cat

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, everyday-life

It is a general statement that cats tend to fall on their feet. How far is this is a valid statement? If I were to drop a cat from 50 meters height, feet  up(hypothetically), would it still land on its feet? But would that violate the angular momentum conservation (if initially the cat has zero spin when dropped) and the law of Inertia?

Comment: Cats do fall on their feet: there are slow-motion films showing how they do this.  This obviously does not violate angular momentum conservation.  In particular remember that the conservation rule applies to the whole cat: if it can temporarily arrange for part of it to have some angular momentum (tail) the rest of it will have equal and opposite AM and will thus spin.  Also note that cats are quite small so they live in a world where air-resistance can be usefully exploited.  Don't drop a cat from 50m up: it will break bones.

Comment: Hence the word hypothetically

Comment: I feel like this has been asked and answered already on this site, but the mobile interface isn't quite functional in this respect.

Comment: It's addressed in the question on [How do astronauts turn in space?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/2954/).

Comment: @Abhinav: sorry, I didn't mean to imply you would.  It is possible to do this experiment from (much) lower heights if you have a cat you are on good terms with.  The interesting thing is that they never land on their side: there's a minimum height below which they don't even try (this experiment needs to be done over a very soft surface like a bed).  And I am not suggesting anyone do these experiments unless it is very clear no distress or harm is caused to the animal!

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24632/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32882/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88322/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Here is a nice video of a cat falling with an explanation.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtWbpyjJqrU

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would belong on a Biomechanics.SE site if such existed

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I'd argue against that: first of all there isn't such a site, and secondly it is actually a physics question I think.  I agree that it may be a duplicate, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been well studied.

Cats use their tails to flip themselves around.  Initially, the inertia of the tail matters.  After a short time, the wind resistance of the tail becomes significant.

Put another way, cat's right themselves using angular momentum, then keep them selves that way using aerodynamics.

Comment: Actually housecats (Felis Sylvestris) don't really use, or need their tail to flip. The wonderful little animation on the ["Cat Righting Reflex" wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_righting_reflex#/media/File:Cat_fall_150x300_6fps.gif) shows how a cat with equal inertia matrices for forward and hinder halves flips. My own cat has been tailless since 2004 when she lost her tail in an accident and neither now has any difficulty making the reflex and took almost no time to learn it again after her tail had to be amputated. "Tailless" flipping means that the rotation is confined to one axis ..

Comment: ... but some tree dwelling cats, such as the Asian Marbled Cat have heavy, clublike tails that are important for their righting reflex because they freely re-orient themselves about all three axes as they dive bomb their prey or sail from one tree to the next.