# Dynamics of a gymnast

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws

Can anybody share some ideas as to how to treat the dynamics of a gymnast's body when they're in air? As in, dynamics of a system consisting of mechanically coupled rigid bodies in a torque free system? My aim is to find out how a gymnast initiates a mid-air twist without any apparent torque.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Rotation Direction in Mid Air](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139055/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88322/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24632/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's how cats do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_righting_reflex)

> After determining down from up visually or with their vestibular
>   apparatus (in the inner ear), cats manage to twist themselves to face
>   downward without ever changing their net angular momentum. They are
>   able to accomplish this with these key steps:
>
> Bend in the middle so that the front half of their body rotates about
>   a different axis from the rear half. Tuck their front legs in to
>   reduce the moment of inertia of the front half of their body and
>   extend their rear legs to increase the moment of inertia of the rear
>   half of their body so that they can rotate their front further (as
>   much as 90°) while the rear half rotates in the opposite direction
>   less (as little as 10°). Extend their front legs and tuck their rear
>   legs so that they can rotate their rear half further while their front
>   half rotates in the opposite direction less. Depending on the cat's
>   flexibility and initial angular momentum, if any, the cat may need to
>   perform steps two and three repeatedly in order to complete a full
>   180° rotation.